# texas holdem split pot

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-history

Me and My friends were playing a game of texas hold em when this hand came out. Player 1 ended up taking the hand, but I'm still confused. Is high card still applied when both players have the same two pair and the high card is already in the pair?
P1: 7,J
P2: 7,2

7,Q,Q,4,9

Answer (score 1):

It is the best **5** card hand.

Player 1 has 7,7,Q,Q,J

Player 2 has 7,7,Q,Q,9

Player 1 has a better hand, they win the pot.